# plink asking for login credentials when already argumented?

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

```
plink 12.34.567.89 -ssh -pw <hidden pass> -l <hidden username> svn update ~/public_html
```

The ip addresss above is hidden/modified

When I execute this, it asks: "login as: _"

But I already supplied my login credentials in the plink command.

I know my credentials are correct, I tested them with putty

Thanks,
Jonah

Comment: It's working fine in my machine.  I don't have an immediate answer for you.  You can do more testing. 1) Try it on some other machines and see if you see the same things. 2) What is the Putty version you are using?  3) It may be because you have a PuTTY session named as "12.34.567.89".  Plink will pull the session information.  One of the settings may force it to prompt you to do login.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and this helped me solve it

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.security.ssh/browse_thread/thread/058b4cf34acd8822

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify your arguments before the IP address:

```
plink -ssh -pw <hidden pass> -l <hidden username> 12.34.567.89 svn update ~/public_html
```